# Partial view updated via ajax does not persist the data

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

in a MVC 5 project, the Index page contains 2 partial views. One to enter the search arguments and the other to show the rates (via ajax call). Everything works as expected and the rates view does show the returned data. What happens is that if the user goes to another page, in the same project, then returns, the rates partial view is empty, although the search arguments in the other partial view are still present. Is there a way to persist the rates data?

// This script is in the index page with the 2 partial views

> ```
> <script>
>     $(function () {
>         $('#viewSearch').submit(function () {
>             if ($(this).valid()) {
>                 $.ajax({
>                     url: '/Home/GetRates',
>                     type: "POST",
>                     cache: true,
>                     dataType: 'html',
>                     data: $("#viewSearch").serialize(),  
>                     success: function (data) {
>                         $('#viewRates').html(data);        
>                     }, 
>                 });
>             }
>             return false;
>         });
>     });
> </script>
> ```

// This is the viewRates

@model Models.Rate

```
<table class="table table-bordered input-sm">

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Notes)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Daily)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("BOOK NOW", "Edit", new { id=item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>   
    }

</table>
```

// and this is the controller

```
    [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult GetRates()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       // code
       ...

       return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/Rates.cshtml", rates);
    }

    return PartialView("~/Home/Contact.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: if the search results are persisted just reload the partial on document.ready

Comment: Yes as Matt suggest just call the AJAX again on document.ready (as you already have the search data)

Comment: The data wasn't persistent as I thought.  It only worked after I stored the data in a Session, instead of a ViewBag as it was originally.

Comment: @BenJunior Let me know if there is anything else that I can add to the answer that will improve it for future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the search results are persisted just reload the partial on document.ready